# Binding Button on_release function not working correctly

Tags: python, kivy

So i have an if else statement. If the Button text is ... this happens and so on. Somehow the text of the Button changes like it should but the bind function doesn't work properly. So when i save program and then try to open any other program, the button text changes to save but the on_release function stays on prepare screenshot and doesn't change to current_training_class.show_plan. I hope it is understandable. Here is my code:

problematic part:

```
 if str(plan_name) + ".png" in os.listdir(main.training_plans_path):
        print("startable")
        self.btn_save_start.text = "Start Program"
        self.btn_save_start.bind(on_release=self.current_training_class.show_plan)
        self.ids.btn_cancel.text = "Zurück"
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.opacity = 1
        self.ids.fav_btn.disabled = False
    else:
        print("saveable")
        self.btn_save_start.text = "Save Program"
        self.btn_save_start.bind(on_release=self.prepare_screenshot)
        self.ids.btn_cancel.text = "Abbrechen"
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.opacity = 0
        self.ids.fav_btn.disabled = True
```

whole class:

```
class CurrentSelfMadePlan(Screen):
name = "currentselfmadeplans"

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(CurrentSelfMadePlan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.scrl_view_3 = ScrollView(
        size_hint_y=.8,
        pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "y": .1},
        do_scroll_x=False,
        do_scroll_y=True,
        size_hint_x=1
    )

    self.scrl_child_3 = GridLayout(
        size_hint_x=1,
        size_hint_y=None,
        cols=2,
        height=30000,
        row_default_height=self.scrl_view_3.height*1.9,
        col_default_width=self.scrl_view_3.width*3.4,
        col_force_default=True,
        row_force_default=True,
        spacing=20,
        pos_hint={"y": .05}
    )

    self.flt_name = FloatLayout(
        size_hint_y=.1,
        pos_hint={"y": .9}
    )

    self.btn_save_start = Button(
        size_hint=(.3, .8),
        pos_hint={"right": .99, "y": .05}
    )

    self.lbl_plan_name = Label(
        color="grey",
        font_size=40,
        size_hint=(1, 1),
        pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "y": 0}
    )
    self.flt_name.add_widget(self.lbl_plan_name)

    self.add_widget(self.scrl_view_3)
    self.scrl_view_3.add_widget(self.scrl_child_3)
    self.add_widget(self.flt_name)

    Clock.schedule_once(self.innit, 1)

def innit(self, dt):
    self.ids.btn_float.add_widget(self.btn_save_start)

def show_selfmade_plan(self, plan_name):
    self.current_training_class = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("currenttraining")

    self.manager.current = "currentselfmadeplans"

    main.current_plan = plan_name

    print("start func: " + plan_name)
    self.lbl_plan_name.text = plan_name

    for exercise in makeplans.plan_details[plan_name]:

        if exercise != "type":
            print("exercise: " + exercise)
            img_path = main.all_exercises_path + "/" + exercise + ".png"

            sp = makeplans.plan_details[plan_name][exercise]["sp"]
            series = makeplans.plan_details[plan_name][exercise]["series"]
            reps = makeplans.plan_details[plan_name][exercise]["reps"]

            if series is None:
                series = ""
                print("changes made: " + series)

            if reps is None:
                reps = ""
                print("changes made: " + reps)

            if sp is None:
                sp = ""
                print("changes made: " + sp)

            img = Image(
                source=img_path,
                size_hint=(1, .8),
                pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "y": .1}
            )

            lbl = Label(
                text=exercise,
                color="black",
                size_hint=(1, .1),
                pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": .9}
            )

            lbl_series = Label(
                text="Series: " + series,
                color="black",
                size_hint=(1, .05),
                pos_hint={"center_x": .25, "y": 0},
                font_size=16
            )

            lbl_reps = Label(
                text="Reps: " + reps,
                color="black",
                size_hint=(1, .05),
                pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "y": 0},
                font_size=16
            )

            lbl_sp = Label(
                text="SP: " + sp,
                color="black",
                size_hint=(1, .05),
                pos_hint={"center_x": .75, "y": 0},
                font_size=16
            )

            flt = FloatLayout(
                pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0}
            )

            flt.add_widget(img)
            flt.add_widget(lbl)
            flt.add_widget(lbl_series)
            flt.add_widget(lbl_reps)
            flt.add_widget(lbl_sp)
            self.scrl_child_3.add_widget(flt)

    self.plan_name = plan_name

    if str(plan_name) + ".png" in os.listdir(main.training_plans_path):
        print("startable")
        self.btn_save_start.text = "Start Program"
        self.btn_save_start.bind(on_release=self.current_training_class.show_plan)
        self.ids.btn_cancel.text = "Zurück"
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.opacity = 1
        self.ids.fav_btn.disabled = False
    else:
        print("saveable")
        self.btn_save_start.text = "Save Program"
        self.btn_save_start.bind(on_release=self.prepare_screenshot)
        self.ids.btn_cancel.text = "Abbrechen"
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.opacity = 0
        self.ids.fav_btn.disabled = True

    if main.current_plan not in main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings:
        main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings.append(main.current_plan)

    if len(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings) > 5:
        main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings.pop(0)

    if main.current_plan in self.manager.get_screen("favouritetrainings").fav_plans:
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.source = main.current_dir + "/ButtonPictures/star-2.png"

    else:
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.source = main.current_dir + "/ButtonPictures/star.png"

def favourites(self):
    self.favourite_trainings_class = self.manager.get_screen("favouritetrainings")
    if self.ids.fav_btn_img.source == main.current_dir + "/ButtonPictures/star.png":
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.source = main.current_dir + "/ButtonPictures/star-2.png"
        self.favourite_trainings_class.fav_plans.append(main.current_plan)
        print("added to favs: " + str(self.favourite_trainings_class.fav_plans) + " Plan: " + str(main.current_plan))

    else:
        self.ids.fav_btn_img.source = main.current_dir + "/ButtonPictures/star.png"
        self.favourite_trainings_class.fav_plans.remove(main.current_plan)
        print("removed from favs: " + str(self.favourite_trainings_class.fav_plans) + " Plan: " + str(main.current_plan))

def prepare_screenshot(self, *args):
    Window.fullscreen = True
    Clock.schedule_once(self.take_screenshot, 3)

def take_screenshot(self, dt):
    p = pyautogui.screenshot()
    p.save(main.training_plans_path + "/" + self.plan_name + ".png")

    selfmade_plans_class = self.manager.get_screen("selfmadeplans")
    selfmade_nextstep_class = self.manager.get_screen("nextstep")
    selfmade_currentselfmadeplan_class = self.manager.get_screen("currentselfmadeplans")
    selfmade_createplan_class = self.manager.get_screen("createplan")

    selfmade_plans_class.scrl_child_2.clear_widgets()
    selfmade_nextstep_class.grd_details_1.clear_widgets()
    selfmade_currentselfmadeplan_class.scrl_child_3.clear_widgets()
    selfmade_createplan_class.widgetscreen.clear_widgets()

    im = IMG.open(main.training_plans_path + "/" + self.plan_name + ".png")
    im_crop = im.crop((0, self.height * .1, self.width, self.height * .95))
    im_crop.save(main.training_plans_path + "/" + self.plan_name + ".png", quality=100)

    for child in MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("createplan").scrl_child_1.children:
        for c in child.children:
            c.disabled = True

    try:
        pickle_save = open('plan_details_dict.pickle', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(makeplans.plan_details, pickle_save)
        pickle_save.close()
        print("saved to pickle")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

    try:
        pickle_save_inpt = open('plan_details_input_dict.pickle', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(makeplans.plan_details_input, pickle_save_inpt)
        pickle_save_inpt.close()
        print("saved to pickle")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

    Clock.schedule_once(self.return_to_normal, .5)

def return_to_normal(self, dt):
    Window.fullscreen = False
    self.manager.current = "mainwindow"
```

if you need any more code or explanation I'll be happy to help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code:

```
self.btn_save_start.bind(on_release=self.prepare_screenshot)
```

doesn't change the `on_release` binding, it only adds to the `on_release` binding. So that every time you call `self.btn_save_start.bind()`, you are adding another binding. If you want to actually change the binding from one method to another, you must remove the previous binding using the `unbind()` method. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.unbind).

Comment: oh wow i didn't even know that this existed because i never had to use it. Thank you so much!